# Error: "index 1624 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1624" when trying to generate a list of words using LDA model

Tags: python, indexing, nlp, lda, topic-modeling

I have a list of lists of game text reviews (in JSON format) that have been lemmatized and applied with bag of words model. I would like to generate a combined final list of the top 30 key words from each game (duplicates removed using tf-idf) using the LDA model so that I can use as input features for future machine learning models. However, when I try to run the code on the text reviews, it gives an indexing error of "index 1624 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1624". Is there any way to increase this index size or whatnot? If possible, I would rather not delete the words that are out of the index bounds because then I would lose some important data...

`game_list = ["shenzhen_combined", "moleksyntez_combined", "gladiabots_combined", "baba_combined", "exapunks_combined", "hrmachine_combined", "infinifactory_combined", "logicbots_combined", "mechanica_combined", "mhrd_combined", "opusmag_combined", "primemover_combined", "quadcowboy_combined", "screeps_combined", "sevenbil_combined", "siliconzeroes_combined", "spacechem_combined", "stonestory_combined", "TIS100_combined", "turing_combined", "whiletrue_combined"]`

```
def gen_keyw_feat(game_list, ntop=5, nwrd=6):
rtrn_list = []

for one_game in game_list:        
    data = load_data(one_game + ".json")["data"]
    stop_words = stopwords.words("english")
    #new_data = rem_stopwords(data)
    new_data = [one_data[1] for one_data in data]

    lemmatized_texts = lemmatization(new_data)
    data_words = gen_words(lemmatized_texts)
    id2word = corpora.Dictionary(data_words)
    texts = data_words
    corpus = [id2word.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]
    
    tfidf = TfidfModel(corpus, id2word=id2word)

    low_value = 0.03
    words = []
    words_missing_in_tfidf = []
    for i in range(0, len(corpus)):
        bow = corpus[i]
        low_value_words = []
        tfidf_ids = [id for id, value in tfidf[bow]]
        bow_ids = [id for id, value in bow]
        low_value_words = [id for id, value in tfidf[bow] if value < low_value]
        drops = low_value_words+words_missing_in_tfidf
        for item in drops:
            words.append(id2word[item])
        words_missing_in_tfidf = [id for id in bow_ids if id not in tfidf_ids]

        new_bow = [b for b in bow if b[0] not in low_value_words and b[0] not in words_missing_in_tfidf]
        corpus[i] = new_bow
    

    rtrn_list += [lda_rslts for lda_rslts in LDA_func(ntop, nwrd, corpus, one_game)]

return list(set(rtrn_list))
```

The output is as follows:

shenzhen_combined 133 1624
moleksyntez_combined 65 1624
gladiabots_combined 117 1624
index 1624 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1624

baba_combined 139 1624
index 1624 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1624

exapunks_combined 150 1624
index 1624 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1624

hrmachine_combined 264 1624
index 1624 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1624

infinifactory_combined 199 1624
index 1624 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1624

logicbots_combined 73 1624
mechanica_combined 69 1624
mhrd_combined 117 1624
index 1624 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1624

opusmag_combined 76 1624
index 1624 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1624

primemover_combined 67 1624
quadcowboy_combined 180 1624
index 1624 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1624

screeps_combined 255 1624
index 1624 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1624

sevenbil_combined 134 1624
index 1624 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1624

siliconzeroes_combined 74 1624
spacechem_combined 438 1624
index 1624 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1624

stonestory_combined 69 1624
TIS100_combined 318 1624
index 1624 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1624

turing_combined 5 1624
whiletrue_combined 119 1624
index 1624 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1624

['coder',
'manual',
'initial',
'hurtin',
'board',
'level',
'fun',
'alike',
'programming',
'job',
'mechanic',
'solitare',
'forever',
'byte',
'badly',
'easy',
'extremely',
'update',
'place',
'command',
'minimized',
'mini',
'once',
'miss',
'win',
'arcane',
'great',
'cocoa',
'balanced',
'then',
'recommend',
'maybe',
'quirk',
'circuit',
'line',
'hour',
'printer',
'jack',
'game',
'count',
'zacktronic',
'challenge',
'hook',
'purely',
'chip',
'documentation',
'neat',
'inadequate',
'somewhere',
'good',
'already',
'approach',
'chuckle',
'electronic',
'away',
'bed',
'last',
'asm',
'controller',
'fundamental',
'so',
'turn',
'micro',
'just',
'rewarding',
'senior',
'mediocre',
'whole',
'at',
'ever',
'number',
'primarily',
'bashingly',
'assembly',
'state',
'zachtronic',
'phone',
'balance',
'thank',
'consideration',
'solitaire',
'pain',
'swing',
'instruction',
'premium',
'thought',
'original',
'forward',
'much',
'difficulty',
'briefly',
'puzzle',
'straightforward',
'tfw',
'halp',
'physical',
'ground',
'inferior',
'screen',
'engineering',
'beautiful',
'home',
'unlikely',
'monotonous',
'unprepared',
'university',
'grasp',
'capability',
'kit',
'diddling',
'helpful',
'more',
'program',
'difficult',
'conditional',
'right',
'thinking',
'setting',
'accomplishment',
'ridiculous',
'codeslp',
'product',
'code',
'quite',
'again',
'character',
'fake',
'day',
'assignment',
'way',
'combination',
'port',
'main',
'friend',
'optimization',
'severe',
'sheet',
'absolutely',
'mind',
'many',
'pressure',
'bonus',
'annoying',
'tool',
'brain',
'smart',
'interesting',
'distro',
'fine',
'fan',
'package']

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're doing with TFIDF, but it's very likely that this causes an inconsistency with the indexes used by LDA, hence the error. You can check easily: if you don't apply the TFIDF filtering, you probably won't have the issue. Also I don't see why you would use TFIDF to remove duplicates (duplicates in top words lists?), it's not really meant for this and there are other ways to catch duplicates.

Comment: Oops, sorry! I meant that the TFIDF was to remove the frequently occurring words because I want to get filter words like "game" or something that's not super descriptive of the game itself. I'm not sure if there's a better way or not for that?

Also, I removed the TFIDF codeblock like you suggested, but am still seeing the same error :(

Comment: I'm not familiar with LDA_func and I don't know what your data looks like so I'm not sure we can debug this. What seems strange to me is that your variable `corpus` is made of 2-tuples (id,word), it doesn't look like the right input format for LDA.